# Edit document is opening document in read-only modus and I cannot check document out in word?

Tags: document-library

I created a new listinstance of type document library. This document library is using my custom contenttype. Also I implemented these version settings below. When clicking on the context menu -> edit, the document will be opened in word but in read-only modus!! I do not see in the top bar some message to check out the document.

1) major and minor versioning enabled.

2) only users with contribute permissions can see draft versions

3) maximum versions for major and minor is 25

4) checkout is required

This is the xml of the listinstance elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance Title="DMS Documenten" OnQuickLaunch="TRUE" TemplateType="101" Url="Lists/DMSDocumenten" Description="DMS Documenten" VersioningEnabled="TRUE"></ListInstance>
  <Receivers ListUrl="Lists/DMSDocumenten">
    <Receiver>
      <Name>DMSEventReceiverItemAdding</Name>
      <Type>ItemAdding</Type>
      <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
      <Class>SharePoint.Intranet.SiteDefinition.DMSEventReceiver</Class>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
    </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

This is the xml of the list element in the schema.xml:

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="DMSDocumenten" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="DMSDocumenten" BaseType="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" ForceCheckout="TRUE" DraftVersionVisibility="1" EnableMinorVersions="TRUE" VersioningEnabled="TRUE" MajorVersionLimit="25" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="25">
```

What is going wrong with my custom listinstance? Other libraries are going fine.

Answer (score 1):

I created the listinstance in c# code in an feature receiver. Then I do not have this issue.